# Error: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1232071d0

Tags: swift, ibaction, unrecognized-selector, uialertaction

I'm doing 2nd challenge of Project 13 of 100 Days of Swift. The task is to: Make the Change Filter button change its title to show the name of the currently selected filter. So, I added "action" of type UIAlertAction as the parameter label of the function, to have an access to the title property. However, I'm receiving unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1232071d0 error. I know this error is related somehow to Objective-C, unfortunately I'm not able yet with my programming skills to move around breakpoints, so it's problematic. I will appreciate any kind of help.

[image]

I've tried to solve this issue (of getting access to the title's property of UIAlertAction) with switch statements, for in loop but unsuccessfully.

Comment: A "selector" is the Objective C terminology for a method call (called a "message" in [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) terms). You've tried sending a message to an Objective C object which doesn't respond to it. E.g. you can capitalize a NSString, but not an NSNumber. If you tried the latter, you would get `-[NSConstantIntegerNumber capitalizedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1029c0038`, telling you that you tried to invoke the instance method (`-`) `capitalizedString` on an instance of `NSConstantIntegerNumber`, but there's no such thing.

Comment: So if you take a deeper look at your error message, you'll see that it tells you which kind of message you were trying to send, and which object you tried to send it to, which didn't support it.

Comment: You need to share the full error message as suggested by @Alexander